# How to avoid python running file in the directory where the code is located?

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm writing a script that will download an executable from the internet, which will create more files. Now, if I download the file, it will be downloaded to the directory I told it, but when I open it using os.startfile(), it creates the files to the directory where the python script is located. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Move the file before opening it? So that the created files are in *that* directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can move the `.py` file to any other directory.
or
You can use [os.chdir()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) to change the current working directory of the script during the runtime.

```
os.chdir('/path/to/directory')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `os.chdir()` before trying to run the executable:

```
os.chdir('<the target folder where you want the files to be created>')
...
os.startfile('<path to where the executable was downloaded>')
```